Method for solving polynomial system without multilinear form?
I am an engineer who is currently working with some network optimization problem during my post graduate study.  During my study time, I see that sometimes I need to look for solution of polynomial equaton system.
From my experience this issue can be deal with quite easily using the Groebner bases. However, I notice that the polynomial system arising from my application does not have multilinear term like $xy,xyz,xyzt$.
For example:
$\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{x^3} + {y^3} = 1241}\\
{{x^2} - {y^2} = -17}\\
{{\rm{some}}\,{\rm{linear}}\,{\rm{equation}}\,{\rm{of}}\,x\,{\rm{and}}\,y}
\end{array}} \right.$
Out of pure curiousity, my question is that does this fact help me solve polynomial system more easily ?
Or maybe exploiting this fact might help calculate the groebner basis more quickly ?
Please help me with this, thank you for your enthusiasm !

If the polynomial system lacks multilinear terms, it might indicate that the equations are decoupled to some extent, which can simplify finding solutions since there may be fewer interactions between variables. However, this doesn't universally make the process easier as the degree of the polynomials and the nature of the nonlinearity still play a significant role.

It also depends on some linear equation of $x$ and $y$, but for such a small system, it will make no difference for solving with or without terms $xy$. In general, systems of polynomial equations are very hard, and it is not feasible to compute a Groebner basis then, so one has to do other things first. For this, we need a more interesting example from you.
